# Conda packed env does not point to right python after unpack

Tags: python, conda, conda-pack

So, I create a conda env the usual way, but with a slight difference. I copy some extra folders to the env root so I can have them packed.

After packing to tar.gz they are there, but when unpacking and activating, it does not point to the right python executable. any ideas?

```
╭─ ~/Downloads  
╰─ mkdir -p my_env
╭─ ~/Downloads  
╰─ tar -xzf my_env.tar.gz -C my_env
╭─ ~/Downloads  
╰─ source my_env/bin/activate
╭─ ~/Downloads                                     my_env
╰─ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented (probably on purpose, to avoid some user issues) `--copy` switch that allow you to have a "portable" conda env:

Example:

```
conda create -p /path/to/new-conda-env --copy python=3 pandas scikit-learn
```

The conda env created at this path can then be zipped and unzipped elsewhere on similar architecture (ie. linux x64 to linux x64). You can also manually add packages if necessary (copy to `site-packages` path).

I use this all the time with PySpark + Hadoop to ship all dependencies without having to install them on cluster.

Comment: so if I have some arbitrary file test.txt I would put it in the env folder prior to the env creation?

Comment: If files are just data files and not modules / code you can put them in the env folder after env creation and zip the whole folder and data files together.
Your code can then use abolute path or env relative path to find data files when running.

Comment: So this means I'll just compress the env folder instead of using conda pack right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It allows for much easier transition to a machine where conda is not / cant be installed.

Comment: awesome. I'll try this. thank you very much.

Comment: another thing, without packing the env there is no bin/activate. How do you activate the env in a machine with no conda

Comment: You can juste call the python binary in the env, if you need activate, it's located on a subdirectory below:

Example:


`source ./lib/python3.9/venv/scripts/common/activate && bin/python3 test.py

cat test.py
import pandas as pd

source ./lib/python3.9/venv/scripts/common/activate && bin/python3
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>`

Comment: BTW sorry, can't find how to format multiline code in comments :/

Comment: still not working. :/ 

```╭─ …/miniconda3/envs                                             __VENV_DIR__
╰─ which python
/usr/bin/python```

Comment: That's because `which` ask your system. To use this env, you need to run it from its path, ie. `/path/unzipped-env/bin/python3`

Comment: you do not need to call the python executable from the env when it is activated.

Comment: Yes but with this method, (--copy) it's not a conda environment, just a Python env which only scope within its directory. It can be used to run scripts / apps using `source /path/to/activate && /path/to/python3 /path/to/app.py`

Comment: Ok, got it. Well, that won't do for me then. :)

Comment: At the minimum if you really need conda and can install it, it will work with `conda activate /path/to/env`. You won't need to have to install python + packages.